# TLE9879 SoC debug interface only works when under-volted

Tags: keil, cortex-m, swd

I'm using a [TLE9879 BLDC Shield](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/evaluation-boards/bldc_shield_tle9879/#!?fileId=5546d462696dbf120169a0bb25396e7d) as a development kit, that is, I'm programming the SoC itself rather than controlling it with an Arduino. The board has a Cortex 10 pin SWD interface, to which I connect a JLink debugger.

When I supply the 12V SoC with 5V, I can flash it and debug the ARM core. The SoC appears slightly under-volted with around 4V on low-voltage pins instead of 5V, but it works. However, when I supply it with 12V, I get "Could not halt CPU after reset" / "CPU could not be halted" errors in Keil, and flashing/debugging doesn't work. I'm certain the chip supports debugging at nominal voltage, my SW can be flashed and debugged on a different dev board with the same chip.

I looked at the SWD line with the scope, and I don't see any problems with signal integrity. The first difference between a successful session and a failed one appears about 2ms after the initial rising edge on the SWD (blue is successful):

[image]

Any ideas what I could try to get the SWD working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced the issue to the P0.2 pin which is connected to the red LED on this board. After reset, the level on this pin desides whenever a debug session is allowed or not:

[image]

The debug cable must pull this pin low (pin 5 of the debug connector), otherwise it will have the voltage of Vdd - Vled. If the cable doesn't pull the pin low, and the chip is properly powered, Vdd = 5V and the voltage on the pin is high enough to be interpreted as 1, so debug mode is disabled.